# Salesforce CPQ Quote Template not updating header and footer

Tags: cpq, header, steelbrick, quote-template

I have Salesforce CPQ (Steelbrick) and am trying to put a custom header and footer on the quote template.  I went to template content, clicked new, selected Template Top, clicked continue and for testing purposes I just changed

```
{!template.SBQQ__CompanyCity__c}, {!template.SBQQ__CompanyState__c} {!template.SBQQ__CompanyPostalCode__c}
```

so that it was above

```
{!template.SBQQ__CompanyStreet__c}
```

and then clicked save.  I then went to Quote Templates, opened the template I wanted to change, and then edited it.  I changed the Header Content to the new Template Top I just created. I then opened a quote and went to preview document. I selected the template I just changed and set the paper size to letter and hit preview.  I end up with the standard header and no change to it.  how to I get the quote template to use my custom header?

Comment: Did you set Header Height? Just guessing but it may not apply the header without a specified height...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_quote_templates.htm&type=5

I missed the part about creating template sections.